# Сделать файловую структуру из списка элементов

Tags: python, файловая-система, дерево

Дан список словарей устроенный следующим образом, каждый элемент имеет имя, id и id родителя.

Каким образом можно составить структуру данных дерево чтобы получить в корне основного родителя (то есть элемент который не имеет родителя, но сам им является), а в ветках элементы, которые являются или сыновьями или родителями.

Реализацию алгоритма писать необязательно, нужна только логика самого решения. Просто я запутался каким способом можно решить данную задачу.

Использование сторонних библиотек исключено. (Если смотреть решение задачи на Python.)

Корневого элемента в списке может не быть, при этом он встречается как id родителя.

Comment: Выбираем все с `parent == None`, далее рекурсивно для каждой найденной ищем с `parent = node['id']`

Comment: @Lecron parent у всех есть.

Comment: рекурсия однако )))

Comment: Значит у вас неполная структура. Её часть. Тогда искать элементы, чьи `parent` не присутствуют в списке доступных id. `node_id = [x['id'] for x in nodes]; parent_nodes = [x for x in nodes if x['parent'] not in node_id]` а дальше, как обычно.